# Plotting time serie grouped in multiple levels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset with the following structure:

```
df = pd.read_csv('daily-minimum-values.csv', header=0, dtype={'Value':float})
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.head()
```

```
+------------+-------+
| Date       | Value |
+------------+-------+
| 1990-01-01 | 20.7  |
+------------+-------+
| 1990-01-02 | 17.4  |
+------------+-------+
| 1990-01-03 | 18.1  |
+------------+-------+
| 1990-01-04 | 15.6  |
+------------+-------+
| 1990-01-05 | 12.4  |
+------------+-------+
```

The dataset is a time serie containing data from 1990 to 2013. I'd would like to visually analyze this time serie year to year, so I've tried to generate a figure with multiple subplots each for year, the problem is I'd also like to show quarter/month/date or date in x-axis, for example:

[Plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvZxf.png)

I need to generate plots for multiple levels of aggregation in x-axis, so I've tried several things.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='A')).plot(x="Date",y="Value") # Group by year and plot date in x-axes
```

Which returns multiple plots but it is complicated to see multiple plots at a glance for comparative purpose:

[Generated plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4bHt.png)

I've tried adding two columns to my dataframe, for year and month expecting it is easier to plot but I dont get how matplotlib works.

```
df["year"]=df.Date.dt.year
df["month"]=df.Date.dt.month
df.groupby('year',"month")["Value"].sum().plot(x='month', y='Value')
```

Which produces the following error:

> ValueError: No axis named month for object type

- How do matplotlib and pandas work for this requeriment?
- How can I get the desired plots?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing the list in groupby(): `df.groupby(['year','month'])` when ever you group on more than one column you need to pass it as a list not as the second param of the groupby function

Comment: @Chris, Thank you for pointing out that. Now I am getting only one plot though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create multiplot grids which is supported by the [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html) python module.
Given a DataFrame `df` with timestamps of type `datetime64[ns]` and some values in column `values` which you wish to visualize, you could split the timestamp information, put them in new columns called `year`, `month` and `day` and then use the `FacetGrid` Function to create a grid of plots. The following python code for example would create a line chart for each month and put them in a sequence of rows.

```
g = seaborn.FacetGrid(df,"month")
g.map(plt.plot,"day","values")
```

Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What is "B" third parameter in `g.map` function?.

Comment: I renamed the column `B` to `values`. `values` is a column which contains values you wish to visualize.